# sql - update internal table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need up update some data in an internal table.  It is the state field.  My result set is 100 rows.

I want to update the first 5 with TX
The next five with DE
The next five with CA

Then start again with TX and continue until I've gone through all 100 rows.

Thanks

Comment: try as CTE with a row_number(), and then CASE within the UPDATE on that row number

Comment: What do you mean by "internal table"?

Answer (score 1):

You need a sequence number in your resulset, if you don't have one use [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to generate it.

```
UPDATE a
SET state = b.state
FROM data AS a
INNER JOIN (VALUES (0, 'TX'), (1, 'DE'), (2, 'CA')) AS b(id, state)
ON b.id = ((a.rownumber - 1) / 5) % 3
```